# .find background-image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to optimize this code to find and replace the background image for the div class mp-e, but i'm struggling to figure out the right piece for the last line of the code. everything else is correct, it's just the .find function that i can't seem to figure out.

**HTML**

```
<center>
  <div class="mp-a"><div class="mp-b"><!-- |g_title| --></div></div>
  <div class="mp-h"> <!-- |posts| --> posts <i class="lar la-star"></i> <!-- |points| --> points</div>
  <div class="mp-c"><div class="mp-d">
  <div class="mp-e" style="background: url(<!-- |field_7| -->);">
    <div class="mp-f"><div class="mp-g">
     <!-- |awards| -->
    </div></div>
  </div>
  </div> </div>
  <a href="<!-- |field_22| -->"><div class="mp-i">Shipper</div></a>
  <a href="<!-- |field_23| -->"><div class="mp-i">Development</div></a>
  <a href="<!-- |field_25| -->"><div class="mp-i">Request</div></a>
</center>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
  $('div[id*="pid_"]:contains([AI=)').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/ \[AI=(.+?)\]/i, '<span class="my_avatar" style="display: none">$1</span>'));
    var myAvatar = $(this).find('span.my_avatar').text();
    $(this).find('div.mp-e background image').attr('src', myAvatar);
  });
</script>
```

any insights would be great. thank you!

Comment: `background-image` is a CSS style, not an element. There's nothing to find.

Comment: Are you trying to find all divs with class mp-e and then change their style to have a different (or a new) background image? Or are you trying to select only those divs which have class mp-e AND have a background-image style already set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS styles are not elements that you can find.

You use the `.css()` method to change the style of an element.

```
$(this).find('div.mp-e').css('background-image', `url(${myAvatar})`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You placed `backgroud` and `image` as HTML elements while they are CSS attributes.

Try this, a bit different than yours

```
$(this).find('div.mp-e').css({
    "background": " url('YOUR IMAGE PATH')"
})
```

To add more CSS attributes add `,` to the object inside the `.css` function then enter your attribute `:` value